# node js Sequelize with MySQL date formate issue

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I developed node js services with Sequelize with MySQL Everything working good. I am storing data in DB with date and time with service but if I get the same data with service, node js automatically converting time (a wrong format which is not in the database), I want same time which is present in the database. to solve this issue I set the timezone in services and in the database but none of them is working. can anyone provide me with the solution.

Comment: post your code.

Answer (score 1):

## suggestion

you could include time format function in mysql
for example

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT("19:30:10", "%H %i %s");
```

result

TIME_FORMAT("19:30:10", "%H %i %s")
19 30 10

[ref](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_time_format.asp)

Answer (score 0):

That's not the issue of node js , **Sequelize by default gives the time in UTC** , so that date time will be correct

**Check :** Just compare your date time with UTC , and check is that you are getting.

**Solution :** So what you can do is , just convert returned date and time to your timezone and you are good to go.

And that's a good practice if you are using UTC everywhere , you can get benefits when you are getting / showing in many countries.